# using if else statements with a timer

Tags: javascript, timer, if-statement

Im trying to set up a series of if else statements using a timer. Ideally, these if else statements would display images according to real time. However, if there is a way to set up my own timer and have the images display using if else statements that would also work. Here's what I'm thinking;

```
if (time < 7:00) {
document.getElementById("whatever").style.display="block";
}
```

Please assist if anyone knows the best possible solution for this particular problem. THANK YOU!!

Comment: For one, `7:00` is not a valid expression.

Comment: Its not really clear what you're trying to achieve.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a condition that becomes truthy when it's earlier than 7pm:

```
if (new Date().getHours() < 19) { }
```

The [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) method returns the hour of the day between 0 and 23.

In a timer function it would look like this:

```
function doMagicStuff()
{
    var now = new Date();

    if (now.getHours() < 19) { 
    }
    // other conditions based on time
}

// let it run approximately every second; doesn't have to be very accurate
setInterval(doMagicStuff, 1000);
```